# Issue with numpy array shape when creating custom image dataset

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am trying to create a custom dataset for a Deep Learning project using jpg images. I need to read them all in one batch. Doing so using the code below, but my array shape is `(100, 1, 224, 224, 3)` instead of `(100,224, 224, 3)`. Any suggestions?

```
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/Training'
X=[]
for img in os.listdir(path):
    pic = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
    pic = cv2.cvtColor(pic,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    pic = cv2.resize(pic,(224,224))
    X.append([pic])
X=np.array(X)
print(X.shape)
```

```
(100, 1, 224, 224, 3)
```

Comment: `X.append(pic)`  It's the [] that are adding the size 1 dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj, did you read my answer?  I wrote exactly the same thing as you commented now.

Answer (score 2):

From general point of view, use `squeeze` from `numpy` to remove unused dimension (with unit length) from tensor.

For example:

```
print(np.squeeze(X).shape)
```

gives you:

> (100, 224, 224, 3)

But perhaps in your case it is enough to use `X.append(pic)` in the line 7 (try to check this).

**Tip**: try to avoid lists when using `numpy`. About @hpaulj comment, you can use the `concatenate` function of `numpy` instead of lists:

```
# initialization like X = []
X = np.zeros([0]+list(pic.shape))
...
# append
X = np.concatenate((X, pic.reshape([1]+list(pic.shape))), axis=0)
```

Comment: lists are best when collecting values iteratively.

Comment: @hpaulj I only wrote "try to avoid" (this is not a restriction), as using lists can increase the calculation time.